# Create a new column conataing list from 2 columns - python

Tags: python

```
Df :

   A              B
2019-09-24 2019-10-01 
2019-09-29 2019-09-29 
2019-09-29 2019-10-25 
2019-10-04 2019-10-11 
2019-10-26 2019-10-26
```

This is a dataframe , I want a third column , as below:

```
   A         B                 C
2019-09-24 2019-10-01  [2019-09-24,2019-10-01]
2019-09-29 2019-09-29  [2019-09-29,2019-09-29]
2019-09-29 2019-10-25  [2019-09-29,2019-10-25]
2019-10-04 2019-10-11  [2019-10-04,2019-10-11]
2019-10-26 2019-10-26  [2019-10-26,2019-10-26]
```

Third column is a addition of first two columns and result in list. how ca we acheive this in python.

Comment: are you using pandas?

Comment: This should do `df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x:x.values, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: [elem for elem in x], axis=1)`

P.S. 
It would helpful to show what you tried.